# Add config file in workbench package for Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

How does one make use of a config file when making L4.2 packages? The kind which can be customized by the user when running `php artisan view:publish`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the component own config directory, you must have a config.php file like this:

```
<?php return ["foo" => "bar"];
```

Then, for reading the value:

```
$this->app['config']->get('%FACADE_NAME%::%CONFIG_VAR%');
```

Ex:

```
$this->app['config']->get('component::foo');
```